# What is the meaning of these symbols about git to the right of the prompt?

Tags: terminal, git, oh-my-zsh

I recently took over maintenance of a server from a now departed colleague and while I'm getting a handle on most of the stuff, one thing that's still a bit confusing is how he's set up the GIT repository on it. Whenever I `cd` to the directory on the server with the repository on it, the stuff on the right hand side of this shot comes up:

[image: git command line prompt]

I know it's to do with the repo - master is the name of the branch, and I'm fairly sure the green plus means an added file, but I'm not sure what the blue `!` , the cyan `?` and the red `-` (which seems to always be there even after I commit everything) mean.

The only possible clue I can come up with as to what set this up is that he put `ohmyzsh` on here but searching that has brought up nothing close to how this looks. What program is doing this and where can I see a list of symbol/colour explanations?

Comment: Looks like your colleague has a custom script for this but we can't know where it is. It could be anywhere. You need to check your shell initialization files and see what they are calling.

Comment: If I were to guess, unstaged and untracked changes. You can experiment to see check which is which quickly enough.

Comment: @muru I think you're probably right, guess I'm going to have to play with it a bit more. Just a shame it's not immediately obvious what's doing the display. Thanks!

Comment: For the sake of anyone looking at this after the fact, I think I figured it all out: red -  = uncommitted file(s) to be deleted, green +  = uncommitted file(s) to be added, blue ! = uncommitted modified file(s), cyan ? = uncommitted untracked file(s)

Comment: As terdon said, check shell initialization files.  You can look at the one bundled with `git` https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh to get a hint as this env likely is something similar.